# How to get StartTime and EndTime for based on Shift wise in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Consider we are working totally three shift.

```
Shift A -->StartTime 7:00:00 AM      EndTime 15:30:00 PM
Shift B -->StartTime 15:30:00 PM     EndTime 11:59:59 PM
Shift c -->StartTime 12:00:00 AM     EndTime 06:59:59 AM
```

I need last third shift start time and end time & Last Running shift Start Time & End Time.

**E.g:**

```
Now, I am in fist shift. Today date is --> 14-Mar-2017 11:13 AM
```

**Need Output like below format :**

```
    Last Third Shift Start Time : 2017-03-13 07:00:00 AM
    Last Third Shift End Time   : 2017-03-14 06:59:59 AM

    Last Running Shift Start Time : 2017-03-13 12:00:00.000
    Last Running Shift End Time   : 2017-03-14 06:59:59.000
```

Comment: Not clear with the question. What do you mean by "Last Three Shift Start Time"?  You mean last third? In that case "Last Three Shift End Time " has to be 2017-03-13 15:30:00 PM right?

Comment: updated the questions & Yes I need last third shift start time and Last Third shift end time. E.g : If i am in first shift (14-Mar-2017 7:00:00 AM) means. I need output for last shirt start time (14-Mar-2017 12:00:00 AM) and End time (14-Mar-2017 6:59:59 AM) & Last third shift start time (14-Mar-2017 07:00:00 AM) End Time (14-Mar-2017 06:59:59 AM)

Comment: Still confused!! how "Last Third Shift End Time " & "Last Running Shift End Time " will be same -2017-03-14 06:59:59.000?

Comment: By mistake i mentioned wrong date. E.g: Last Three Shift means today is 14th March 2017. Now we are in first shift & the time is 14:17pm. I want Last day First shift start time like '13-Mar-2017 07:00:00 am' & Last Shift EndTime like (14-Mar-2017 06:59:59) and Last Running Shift Start Time (2017-Mar-14 12:00:00 AM) and Last Running Shift End Time (06:59:59 AM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #tmp
 (
 shiftstarttime datetime,
 shiftendtime datetime
 )
 insert into #tmp values ('1-Jan-2017 7:00:00','1-Jan-2017 15:30:00')
 insert into #tmp values ('1-Jan-2017 15:30:00','1-Jan-2017 23:59:59')
 insert into #tmp values ('2-Jan-2017 00:00:00','2-Jan-2017 06:59:59')

 declare @currdate datetime=getdate()
  declare @lastdate datetime=dateadd(d,-1,getdate())
 declare @tab table
 (
  RankID int identity,
  starttime datetime,
  endtime datetime
 )
 insert into @tab  
 select dateadd(d,datediff(d,shiftstarttime,@currdate),shiftstarttime), dateadd(d,datediff(d,shiftendtime,@currdate),shiftendtime)
 from #tmp
 UNION
  select dateadd(d,datediff(d,shiftstarttime,@lastdate),shiftstarttime), dateadd(d,datediff(d,shiftendtime,@lastdate),shiftendtime)
 from #tmp

 select starttime as LastThirdShiftStartTime,endtime as LastThirdShiftEndTime
 from @tab where RankID = (select RankID from @tab where @currdate between starttime and endtime)-3
 select starttime as LastRunningShiftStartTime,endtime as LastRunningShiftEndTime
 from @tab where RankID = (select RankID from @tab where @currdate between starttime and endtime)-1

 drop table #tmp
```

You can try this sample code. I have stored the shift timings in a temp table and based on current server time it will give you the last 3rd shift start and end time and last shift start and end time.

Comment: @Dhamo, that's great!! Please mark as an answer if that code satisfies your requirement.  Thank you!!